# Unable to install gnome-shell on Ubuntu Maverick 10.10

Tags: linux, ubuntu, shell, gnome, aptitude

I run:

```
mojo@mojo:~/Downloads$ sudo apt-get install gnome-shell
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 gnome-shell : Depends: mutter but it is not going to be installed
```

it asks for mutter, yet mutter is already installed. I think it asks for different version of mutter.

Date: 7/8/2010

Answer (score 1):

Maverick is not due to be released until October 2010. You should check [Launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/maverick/+bugs) to see if this is a known issue and report it if not.

Answer (score 0):

did more research:

theres a new gjs library, libgjs0a; it conflicts with libgjs0. it wants to install version  0.7+git20100807.847dfe85-0ubuntu1~10.10~ricotz3. but thats not compatible with mutter. so thus breaking gnome-shell (<= 2.31.2-1ubuntu1) but 2.31.2-1ubuntu1.

SHOULD probably be up and running in the next few updates

Comment: I am on vanilla maverick, it should has nothing to do with ricotz ppa btw